# TextView on top of VrPanoramaView

Tags: android, virtual-reality

I am working on VR concepts. I am facing some problems while implementing following scenario. I am able to load the 360° image into the app by using VrPanoramaView. After that I want to draw one more view on top of VrPanoramaView. So I am using the following snippet for that.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setTextColor(R.color.white);
tv.setText("Random TextView");
tv.setId(123);
panoWidgetView.addView(tv);
```

But the problem is after opening the image in VR mode, I am not able to see the textview which I added. I would like to know few things.

1. Is it possible to load a view on top of VrPanoramaView?
2. Why is it difficult to implement the above scenario?
3. How can we get the control over the VrPanoramaView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you trying to add it? i've done something similar with success, maybe i've misunderstood your question.

Comment: PankWidgetView is the panaroma view and I am trying to add the text view in the same way which I have mentioned in the question. It would be great if you share any helpful links.

Comment: I've just set up a layout containing the VrPanoramaView and the TextView, inside a RelativeLayout, and it displayed as so.. that's why I'm telling you that I might have misunderstood your question because this seems pretty straightforward to me :/

Comment: Post the XML or code that contains the VrPanoramaView.